# Enable/Disable AD user with LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is it possible to enable (or disable) a user in Active Directory with LDAP command?

And also, is it possible doing it with C#?

I've already looked 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053269/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-an-ad-user-account-with-an-ldap-request)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820883/enable-an-active-directory-user-with-ldap-java)

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you use powershell with LDAP? What programming languages are you looking to implement the Lda protocol?

Comment: @AndersonOki as i wrote I'm gonna use C#.NET. I prefer using C# because I have to develop a web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PrincipalContext to enable/ disable AD account.
To Enable the AD you can do something like this:

```
 private static void EnableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
     {
       try
    {                
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
                (principalContext, username);

        userPrincipal.Enabled = true;

        userPrincipal.Save();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
 }
```

To disable Active Directory you can just set the **userPrincipal.Enabled = false;**

Comment: this worked, but with this modification `PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName, DomainAdmin, DomainPassword);`

Comment: @Jack, there is no need to supply DomainAdmin, and DomainPassword. It should work on your machine as far as your computer belongs to the domain and the user is logged in.

Answer (score 6):

using this reference [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#43)

you can use "**userAccountControl**" attribute to enable and disable

> you need to pass [DirectoryEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to the function

Enable:

```
public static void Enable(DirectoryEntry user)
    {
        try
        {
            int val = (int)user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
            user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val & ~0x2;
            //ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT;

            user.CommitChanges();
            user.Close();
        }
        catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
        {
            //DoSomethingWith --> E.Message.ToString();

        }
    }
```

---

Disable :

```
public void Disable(DirectoryEntry user)
{
    try
    {
        int val = (int)user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
        user.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x2; 
             //ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;

        user.CommitChanges();
        user.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //DoSomethingWith --> E.Message.ToString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using: [Morgan Tech Space](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Enable-and-Disable-Active-Directory-User-Account-in-CSharp.html) as Reference:

**Enable Active Directory User Account via userAccountControl using C#**

```
private static void EnableADUserUsingUserAccountControl(string username)
 {
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry domainEntry = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().GetDirectoryEntry();
        // ldap filter
        string searchFilter = string.Format(@"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)
                (!sAMAccountType=805306370)(|(userPrincipalName={0})(sAMAccountName={0})))", username);

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domainEntry, searchFilter);
        SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
        if (searcher != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

            int old_UAC=(int)userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];

            // AD user account disable flag
            int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2;

            // To enable an ad user account, we need to clear the disable bit/flag:
            userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] = (old_UAC & ~ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE);
            userEntry.CommitChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Active Director User Account Enabled successfully 
                                      through userAccountControl property");
        }
        else
        {
            //AD User Not Found
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Disable Active Directory User Account via userAccountControl using C#**

```
private static void DisableADUserUsingUserAccountControl(string username)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry domainEntry = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().GetDirectoryEntry();
        // ldap filter
        string searchFilter = string.Format(@"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)
              (!sAMAccountType=805306370)(|(userPrincipalName={0})(sAMAccountName={0})))", username);

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domainEntry, searchFilter);
        SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
        if (searcher != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

            int old_UAC = (int)userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];

            // AD user account disable flag
            int ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2;

            // To disable an ad user account, we need to set the disable bit/flag:
            userEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] = (old_UAC | ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE);
            userEntry.CommitChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Active Director User Account Disabled successfully 
                                through userAccountControl property");
        }
        else
        {
            //AD User Not Found
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Enable AD User Account via UserPrincipal using C#**

```
private static void EnableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
{
    try
    {                
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
                (principalContext, username);

        userPrincipal.Enabled = true;

        userPrincipal.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Active Director User Account Enabled successfully through UserPrincipal");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Disable AD User Account via UserPrincipal using C#**

```
private static void DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
{
    try
    {
        // To use this class, you need add reference System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement which
```

is available only from .NET 3.5;
            PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

```
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
                (principalContext, username);

        userPrincipal.Enabled = false;

        userPrincipal.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Active Director User Account Disabled successfully through UserPrincipal");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```